# Spring Data Rest ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring

I am getting

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get property 'objects' on null object*

error when I intentionally test spring data rest api simulating a user passing bad url as in

http://myurl/findByDate?year=&month="

The year and month are Integers , but in this case I am simulating the user not passing any value.

The app is using the:

```
public interface myRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<myClass, Long> {}
```

interface and there is no explicit controller provided in a controller class.  The data rest interface provides the following:

```
   @Query("Select c from myPOJO c where (YEAR(c.myDate) = :year AND MONTH(c.myDate) = :month)")
    Page findByDate(@Param("year") int year,
                            @Param("month") int month,
                            Pageable pageable);
```

I can see why the exception is being thrown ... but providing a generic exception handler to handle it does not seem to resolve the issue.

```
    @ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        error.setMessage("Please contact your administrator");
        //return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```

Any advise on how to trap this data rest exception would be appreciate it.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get property 'objects' on null object

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by using the object Integer instead of the primitive Int for the param.   This appears to handle the conversion to default value and avoid nulls.

Thanks